# How can I extend Laravel Dusk Browser?

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I wish to override \Laravel\Dusk\Browser methods and extend it with my own, plus a few enhancements. Here is what I did so far but it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tests\Browser\SequentialAppTest::Tests\Browser{closure}() must be an instance of Tests\MyBrowser, instance of Laravel\Dusk\Browser given,
>   called in 
>   /var/www/gtest/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php on
>   line 67
>
> /var/www/gtest/tests/Browser/SequentialAppTest.php:135
>   /var/www/gtest/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:67
>   /var/www/gtest/tests/Browser/SequentialAppTest.php:157

file: tests/MyBrowser.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

class MyBrowser extends \Laravel\Dusk\Browser 
{

}
```

file: tests/Browser/SequentialAppTest.php
    namespace Tests\Browser;

```
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Tests\MyBrowser as Browser;

...

class SequentialAppTest extends DuskTestCase 
{
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `newBrowser()` in your test or in `DuskTestCase`:

```php
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Tests\MyBrowser as Browser;

class SequentialAppTest extends DuskTestCase 
{
    protected function newBrowser($driver)
    {
        return new Browser($driver);
    }
}
```